# passwd: Module is unknown when creating CentOS 7 domU on Jessie

Tags: centos, xen, pam, passwd

DomU created by xen-tools using the command below:

> sudo xen-create-image --hostname=test --dhcp --memory=256mb --install-method=rinse --dist=centos-7  --arch=amd64 --lvm=VM --bridge=xenbr-48 --noswap --fs=ext4 --size=5Gb

Everything goes well until:

```
Setting up root password
Changing password for user root.
passwd: Module is unknown
Do you want to try to change the password again?? [Y/n]:
```

Retries fail with the same error. I tried to set the root password in chroot but `passwd root` failed with the same error. I guess something is missing in `/etc/rinse/centos-7.packages` but I have no idea what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module that is missing is pam_pwquality.so, fixed by `sudo yum install libpwquality`